# Is there an equivalent of 'this' in C# for static members?

Tags: c#

Is there an equivalent of `this` in C# for static members?

I like to use `this` to make my code more readable, but wondered if there was an equivalent for static members.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.I appreciate now that the simple answer to this questions is 'no', but my point was to find out if there was a way of distinguishing between a static member belonging to the class you're working in or a member of another class.  My conclusion is that, stylistically, it would be best to use the class name when working in another class (a prerequisite anyway) and no class name when in the class itself. I shall award the answer to @AakashM for the prompt and exhaustive (or exhausting) explanation. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suppose if you use `this.` to reinforce that you are referring to instance members, the equivalent in a static member would be to use `ClassName.`

But stylistically, why add code that doesn't change meaning?

---

***edit*** to add various clarifications:

My last sentence above can be illustrated with these examples:

```
class Example1
{
    public int J { get; set; }

    public Example1()
    {
        J = 0;
    }

    // These two methods have *exactly* the same CIL
    public int InstanceMethodLong()
    {
        return this.J;
    }

    public int InstanceMethodShort()
    {
        return J;
    }
}
```

The `this.` in `InstanceMethodLong` does not change the meaning as compared with `InstanceMethodShort`.

Statically:

```
class Example2
{
    public static int K { get; set; }

    static Example2()
    {
        K = 0;
    }

    // These two methods have *exactly* the same CIL
    public int StaticMethodLong()
    {
        return Example2.K;
    }

    public int StaticMethodShort()
    {
        return K;
    }
```

The `Example2.` in `StaticMethodLong` does not change the meaning as compared with `StaticMethodShort`.

In both these cases, adding the qualifier results in the same CIL, the same behaviour, and is more source to write, read, and understand. **Stylistically** - and I will happily accept that this is a question of code style - I see no reason for it to be there.

---

With underscore prefixes the situation is slightly different:

```
class Example3
{
    int _j;

    public int J
    {
        get { return _j; }
        set
        {
            _j = value;
            // and do something else,
            // to justify not using an auto-property 
        }
    }

    public Example3()
    {
        J = 0;
    }

    public int MethodWithParameter(int j)
    {
        // Now there is a *difference* between
        return j;

        // and
        return _j;
    }
}
```

Here, in `MethodWithParameter`, there is a *difference* between referring to `_j` and `j` - so we are deliberately and explicitly expressing different meaning. It's true that the compiler doesn't care what we call our variable names, but it *does* care what variables we are referring to! So in the body of `MethodWithParameter`, using or not using an underscore *isn't* just stylistic, it's semantic. Which isn't the particular issue we're addressing in this question.

Comment: It might change the meaning to the *maintainer* of the code. The compiler doesn't care one way or the other.

Comment: Is there a way to make this type-unaware a la 'selftype.name'?  (i.e. if I want to rename my class)

Comment: @Eric I indeed agree that "code should be primarily written for people and only incidentally for computers" - BUT we're at the top of a *very* slippery slope - I'd prefer to aim to be in a place where my fellow maintainers understand my intent in exactly the same way as the compiler does, rather than catering for incomplete understanding in my fellow maintainers. What's next, "avoid LINQ because some people find it confusing" ?

Comment: @xtofl Certainly with ReSharper, such references will get changed as part of a class rename. I *think* the native VS 2010 rename refactoring also does this.

Comment: @xtofl If you use a proper refactoring tool, it will already do that work for you.

Comment: @AakashM - Just wondering, are you suggesting not using static methods? Is there a way you could illustrate the last statement in your answer?

Comment: @AakashM Many devs use "_" to prefix instance variable names. The compiler also does not care about this **but** it does help when reading the code - it's a little bit of extra helpful information. Using "_" and "this." are stylistic but often helpful, a bit like using sensible variable names. The compiler also doesn't care about variable names, but that's no excuse to use "x,y,z" all over the place.

Comment: @Jared @chibacity expanded to (hopefully) clarify what I mean

Answer (score 3):

As a static member is not meant to belong to any particular instance (as `this` refers to an instance of an object, with different settings possible per instance), what you would instead want to do is use `ClassName.Member` instead of `this.Member`.

```
public class Orange
{
    public static string Tastes = "sweet";

    public static string FoodType(){
        return "fruit";
    }
}
```

Would be called by:

```
Console.WriteLine(Orange.Tastes);
```

Same goes for static methods, as well:

```
Console.WriteLine(Orange.FoodType()).
```

Please note this is a contrived example for demonstration only. :)

Answer (score 2):

You may able to use the class name to reference other static properties.

Your code becomes a bit more resistant to copy/paste but that's not always a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, there is no `this` for static methods. To help differentiate static members from class members I prefix it with the class name.

```
class Test {
  static Regex TextRegex = new Regex(...);

  public static bool TestString(string input) {
    return Test.TextRegex.IsMatch(input);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like "this" as well to realsie from the first look where the state is changing. You may want to consider type's name for static members in this case.